# Does the Asus P8Z68-V LX support 3rd generation Intel Core I5 processors?

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I'm having some trouble shopping for a hardware upgrade while trying to stay within budget.

According to the [specifications on their web page](http://ca.asus.com/en/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1155/P8Z68V_LX/#specifications), the P8Z68-V LX provides the following CPU supoprt:

> Intel® Socket 1155 for **2nd Generation** Core™ i7/Core™ i5/Core™ i3 Processors
>
> Supports Intel® 32 nm CPU
>
> Supports Intel® Turbo Boost Technology 2

However according to the product [CPU Support List](http://ca.asus.com/en/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1155/P8Z68V_LX/#CPUS), the Core i5-3570K and other 3rd generation Intel Core processors are listed (note that the 3570K is 22nm).

Does this mean the board will support these processors? Full support or will there be a performance cap? Is a BIOS upgrade required?

I'd like to get the P8Z68-V LX along with a Core i5-3570K and some 1600 MHz DDR3s. The motherboard is a good deal for what I'm looking for, as long as it can support this CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes, *if* you have an updated bios that supports it - the Sandy Bridge (2nd generation core) and Ivy Bridge (3rd generation core) processors share the same socket, and you can upgrade from SB to IB chips in most cases - just get the bios revision that does this for you. My newer asus lets you update the bios without a chip in place, but checking and updating the bios with the older chip pre-swapover is likely to end up being easier